# symfony 6 unable to install hwi/oauth-bundle

Tags: hwioauthbundle, symfony6

I was wondering if anyone has had issues trying to install this with symfony 6. I have a feeling i'm missing something easy, but not sure what.

I am trying to integrate a keycloak user solution and from what i was reading this would be a good way to do it? Unsure if anyone has any better reccomendations?

I see version 2 should be compatible with symfony 6, but it's complaining of lock file versions for some reason.

composer require hwi/oauth-bundle
Using version ^1.4 for hwi/oauth-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update hwi/oauth-bundle
Loading composer repositories with package information
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "6.1.*"
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- hwi/oauth-bundle[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.5] require symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4|^5.1 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.45, v5.1.0, ..., v5.4.12] but the package is fixed to v6.1.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
- Root composer.json requires hwi/oauth-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.5].

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the version 2 by running

```
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:2.0.x-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no released version of `hwi/oauth-bundle` that is compatible with Symfony 6 so far. I see three options:

- wait for a proper release (which might take some more time, as the list of commits within the last months is not that long)
- install the current, unstable beta version (`composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:2.0.0-BETA2`)
- use any alternative package that is already compatible with Symfony 6, like `knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle`