# Symfony 6.1 - Installation of "hwi/oauth-bundle" throws "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, symfony, package, composer-php, bundle

I run the following command in a PHP 8.1 / Symfony 6.1 project:

```bash
compose require hwi/oauth-bundle
```

I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - hwi/oauth-bundle[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.5] require symfony/framework-bundle ^4.4|^5.1 -> found symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.0, ..., v4.4.46, v5.1.0, ..., v5.4.13] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (6.1.5).
    - Root composer.json requires hwi/oauth-bundle ^1.4 -> satisfiable by hwi/oauth-bundle[1.4.0, ..., 1.4.5].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: According to the documentation, it does not officially support Symfony 6 yet.

Comment: You’ll want to follow [this issue](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1880) probably

Comment: Does this answer your question? [symfony 6 unable to install hwi/oauth-bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73562011/symfony-6-unable-to-install-hwi-oauth-bundle)

Comment: the bundle is installed with this command

```composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:2.0.x-dev```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to issue [hwi/HWIOAuthBundle#1880](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/1880) there is no official support for Symfony 6 (yet).

Symfony 6 support will be added in version `2.x` of the bundle.

Until there is an official `v2.x` release  release you can use the following command to install the `2.x` beta versions of `hwi/oauth-bundle` with Symfony `6.x`.

```bash
compose require hwi/oauth-bundle:2.0.x-dev
```

You can verify it quickly in a temporay directory with the Symfony CLI:

```bash
symfony new --version=6.1 /tmp/symfony-6.1
cd /tmp/symfony-6.1
composer require template
composer require hwi/oauth-bundle:2.0.x-dev
rm -rf /tmp/symfony-6.1
```

Installs fine.